# PowerApp - Common Data Service Boolean Missing

Tags: powerapps, common-data-service

Seems like the new version of CDS boolean is missing. Is this an error or what is recommended to use with the toggle control in PowerApps?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "Two options" data type, and it will be represented as a toggle control in PowerApps.

[image]